# Why when transferring data from client to server via API method parameters don't init?

Tags: c#, angular

I have a post method on Angular that sends data to the server:

```
addData(usersId: number[], description?: string) {
const specUrl = HOST_URL + '/api/Doctors/addtoblacklist';
description = 'Test';

return this.http.post(specUrl, {
  usersId, description
});
}
```

And I have a method on AspNet Core that accepts data from the client:

```
    [HttpPost("addtoblacklist")]
    public IActionResult AddToBlackList(int[] usersId, string description)
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(User.Identity.Name, out var doctorId))
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Wrong claims" });
        }

        var status = _doctorService.AddToBlackList(usersId, doctorId);

        return status ? (IActionResult)Ok() : BadRequest();
    }
```

In debug, when the method `addData` works, I get into the method `AddToBlackList`, but the parameters `usersId` and `description` are always null. Usually these problems occurred when variables of different types, or differently named, or one of them using UpperCase. All this I've tried ... Generally I do not understand what the problem may be... Maybe somebody has some ideas? I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return this.http.post(specUrl, {
     usersId:usersId, 
     description:description
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but it did not help, it's still on the server `usersId` and `description` are null

Comment: in debug model , chec the  Content-Type: application/json

Comment: perhaps , this link is useful  for you . http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

Comment: I passed the third parameter `httpOptions`, but it did not help either `httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  };`

Answer (score 0):

I created a model

```
public class AddToBlackListModel
{
    public int[] id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

and used it in [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost("addtoblacklist")]
    public IActionResult AddToBlackList([FromBody] AddToBlackListModel creationModel)
    {
        // 
        if (!int.TryParse(User.Identity.Name, out var doctorId))
        {
            return BadRequest(new { message = "Wrong claims" });
        }

        var status = _doctorService.AddToBlackList(creationModel.id, doctorId);

        return status ? (IActionResult)Ok() : BadRequest();
    }
```

after that all worked) thank you all)